# "durch Abschließen der Tür niemanden zu sich hereinlassen" What is the meaning of 'zu sich'?

Tags: meaning

In Duden's [explanation of *einschließen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einschlieszen) it says:

> durch Abschließen der Tür niemanden zu sich hereinlassen

What does **zu sich** mean in the above sentence?

I am not able to relate this phrase meaningfully to the sentence. However I assume it may have meaning "towards someone", is that correct?

Comment: I am not able to relate this phrase meaningfully to the sentence, however if I assume it may have meaning "towards someone"

Comment: _towards someone_ Not really. In the English translation, it completely disappears (_don't let anyone in by locking the door_). With other examples the closest translation seems to become _yourself_ (_zu sich einladen_ => _invite to yourself_).

Comment: I have edited the question for you now. Take care to be clear from start next time you ask please.

Answer (score 6):

- durch Abschließen der Tür

  > by locking the door
- niemanden hereinlassen

  > let nobody in; don't let anybody in
- zu sich

  > to yourself

> - German:
>   Die Phrase »sich einschließen« bedeutet »durch Abschließen der Tür niemanden zu sich hereinlassen«.
> - English:
>   The phrase "lock yourself in" means "don't let anyone in to yourself by locking the door".

You also could lock the door from outside to let nobody in, but this is not the meaning of "sich einschließen". "Sich einschließen" means, that you are in the room that is locked.

The words "zu sich" express a direction. They mean "towards the speaker". Also the prefix "her-" in "hereinlassen" indicates, that the speaker is in the room. (The prefix "her-" means a movement towards the speaker.)

Comment: Would it be possible to use  the other dative pronoun with "zu"?

Comment: @ughitudhi: Yes. If you want to know more details, pleaser ask a question. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask